# How to prove $({\log_2 x})^{n+1} \le x^n$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, asymptotics

I want to show that $({\log_2 x})^{n+1} \le x^n$ when $n \ge 1$ and $x \ge 1$.

I know that ${\log_2 x}$ can be shown to be $\lt x$ with:

$x \lt 2^x$

$\log_2 x \lt x$

and obviously adding the same exponent to either side would maintain this inequality but is there an equally straightforward way to prove that $({\log_2 x})^{n+1} \le x^n$ ?

Comment: $n=-1$, $x=2$ is a counterexample. What are $x$ and $n$ exactly ?

Comment: For $x=4$ and $n \geq 2$ this is not true.

Comment: @AnteP. If $x=4$, then the inequality becomes $2^{n+1}\le 4^n=2^{2n}$, i.e. $2^{n-1}\ge 1$, which is true for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @user236182 Yes, you are right, what a nonsense I wrote.

Comment: @AnteP. You should delete the comment then.

Comment: @user236182 Nope, it should stay where it is.

Comment: I meant for all $n \ge 1$ and $x \ge 1$. I will change my question to reflect that.

Comment: @user236182 I'm particularly interested in n = 3

Answer (score 2):

$({\log_2 x})^{n+1} \le x^n$ for $n \ge 1$ and $x \ge 1$ is
equivalent to
$$
  \frac {\ln x}{\ln 2} \le x^a
$$
for $x \ge 1$, where $\ln$ is the natural logarithm, and $a = \frac{n}{n+1}$
is a real number in the range $\frac 12 \le a < 1$.

A simple analysis shows that the function
$$
 f(x) = \frac {\ln x}{\ln 2} - x^a
$$
is increasing on $[1, x_0]$ and decreasing on $[x_0, \infty)$ where
$$
 x_0 = \frac{1}{(a \ln 2)^{1/a}} > 1 \quad .
$$
So the desired inequality holds for all $x \ge 1$ if and only if
$$
 f(x_0) = \frac{-\ln a - \ln \ln 2 - 1}{a \ln 2} \le 0 \\
\Longleftrightarrow a \ge \frac{1}{e \ln 2} \approx 0.53074 \\
\Longleftrightarrow n \ge \frac{1}{e \ln 2 - 1 } \approx  1.131 \quad .
$$
If you consider only positive *integers* $n$ then the inequality holds
for all $x \ge 1$ exactly if $n \ge 2$.

For $n=1$, a counter-example is $x=8$: $ (\log_2 8)^2 = 3^2 = 9 > 8$.